# JHipster Create user without requiring activation

Tags: oauth, jhipster

I am usgin JHipster with OAUTH authentication. I would like to create a user without the user activating the account via email. I have modified the code in the UserService thinking that by setting the resetKey and resetDate to NULL, the user can login without the activation step; the `activated` is also set to `true` upon creation. Currently, a user created without the activation email gets:

`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}`

The only way the new user can login is via the Activation email and resetting the password.

Is there any way a user can be created without this step? Is there another authentication table to modify?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I found the bug here
```
protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    Object salt = null;
    if(this.saltSource != null) {
      salt = this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);
    }

```
if(authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
  this.logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
  throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
} else {
  String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
  // PROBLEM IS INVALID PASSWORD!!!!
  if(!this.passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(), presentedPassword, salt)) {
    this.logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");
    throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
  }
}
```

}
```

For some reason my password is not valid and salt is NULL! I have no idea why this is the case. The password I see is the one I created the user with!

Thanks.

Comment: Should be activated and activationKey. Activated default value is false, see User.

Comment: Thanks Gaël, I even tried to set the activationKey to NULL when I create the user and I still get the same error. The activated flag is true even in the DB. I don't know what's missing yet! Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Gaël, your hint was the right one, if you give your comment as an answer I can accept it and you will be rich :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields should be `activated` and `activationKey`. Activated default value is false, see `User.java`.

Answer (score 1):

In UserService.registerUser make:

**newUser.setActivated(true);**

This will make the user active upon register. skipping the email verification.